# Make Codename One text area full width

Tags: textarea, codenameone

[image: This]
I am having trouble getting the text in the text area to span full width. Somehow it just won't stretch even if I adjust the number of columns.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Problem solved. See my comment below.

Comment: I've managed to fix this. Apparently, I applied some UIID to the 'Unselected' style but forgot to apply the same style to 'Selected/Pressed' style.

By default, the textarea had received focus hence 'Selected' style was applied.